# Problems with git-push

Tags: git, git-push

We are a group of developers from the city of St. Petersburg, Russia.
Now we are introducing Git in our development.
We are running on the Ubuntu operating system.
We have personal computers and shared data storage.

We have a task: 1) create a remote repository on a shared data store. 2) create local repositories on personal computers.

We do the following:

1. create a remote empty repository with the command "git init --bare";
2. create a local repository in the project folder with the "git init" command;
3. connect the remote repository to the local one with the command "git remote add 'Name' 'URL'";
4. create a commit in the local repository with the "git add ." and "git commit -m "Message";
5. push the first local commit to the remote repository with the command "git push -u 'Name' master".

When pushing the first commit to the remote repository, the following errors occur:

1. remote: fatal: write error: Unsupported operation;
2. error: failure during external unpacking index-pack abnormal exit;
3. error: Failed to send some links in "URL".

When creating test remote and local repositories with one text file, the above procedure works fine, but it does not work with a project folder that has about 6 thousand files (including program code).

Please help me figure out this problem.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: The text in the error message must be in English. Please switch locale to C.

Comment: The immediate source of the failure is represented by the `remote: fatal: write error: Unsupported operation` string. This comes about because the client side Git reports, to the user running `git push`, any error messages that came from the remote Git. The remote Git sent this error message (`fatal: write error: Unsupported operation`) as a generic error, probably due to a hook script that the server ran, but in any case not from something Git itself thinks is a "normal" error as those would be reported differently.

Comment: The problem now needs to be diagnosed on the server side, by inserting an appropriate tracing system there. How you can do that is up to you...